# Animated GIF background only showing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gif, animated-gif

So on click of these polaroid like images, I replace them with `<div class="poof"></div>` using jQuery's `.replaceWith()`. The reason I do this is to display a poof animated gif animation that I style to that class with js.

However, **on click of the `.polaroid`, the polaroid images, the `.poof` div replaces that html every time, but its background never shows.**

[Try it for yourself, here](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcLVpPcjl3SnBUYXc/index.html):

Click an image, it is replaced by the `.poof` div, but the poof animation doesn't show.

I would greatly appreciate it someone could help me figure out why this is and how to get the animation to show each time.

Here is my javascript:

```
   $(function(){
        var time=1;
        $('.polaroid').click(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith('<div class="poof"></div>');
            $('.poof').css('height', $(this).height()).css('width', $(this).width()).css('background', 'transparent url(poof.gif?t='+time+') center no-repeat');
            time++;
        });
});
```

Here is `.poof`'s CSS:

```
.poof{
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
 }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to add a random query string on the end of the URL to `poof.gif` - like `url(poof.gif?t=12345)` for each time it's used.

Comment: I think you may need to toggle the visibility of the gif so that it will render again.

Comment: @ahren Ah, that makes sense. However, it is not working. [Here is the code that I am using](https://gist.github.com/theirf/25f08f832708e12de50d). [Here is a live example](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcLVpPcjl3SnBUYXc/index.html). The poof animation gif doesn't show on any of them.

Comment: @gomangomango - Can you make it a http://jsfiddle.com ? That way we can all edit it easily.

Comment: @ahren Yes, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/RyWtT/

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the height and width of an object that was remove / replaced in the DOM

Change to this:

```
var heights = 32;
var widths = 32;
$('.polaroid').click(function(){
    heights = $(this).height();
    widths = $(this).width();
    $('.poof').css('height', heights).css('width', widths).css('background', 'transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/FsVe2LC.gif?t='+time+') center no-repeat');
    time++;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.poof').remove();
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Yes you're basically right, but you also want to consider that a person could be visiting the site again and have those incremental query string values cached. Try using `var time = (new Date()).getTime();` - also consider that you're updating all elements with a class of `.poof` - so the animation would replay if there was another `.poof` - the easier way to fix this (rather than remove the element) is to target it using a dynamically generated class. Like `'.poof-'+time`